# Callback Function in jQuery .ready()

Tags: jquery, svg, callback

```
var county = 
[
    ["Beaverhead", 0],
    ["Deer Lodge", 0],
    ["Flathead", 0],
    ["Gallatin", 0],
    ["Golden Valley", 0],
    ["Park", 0]
];

function colorMap()
{
    for (var j = 0; j < county.length; j++)
    {
        console.log(county[j]);
        if( county[j][1] > 0 )
        {
            $('#' + county[j][0]).css({'fill': '#0000FF'});
        }
    }       
}

$(document).ready(function loader(colorMap){
var loop = 0;
    var offset = 0;
    while (loop < 2)
    {
        console.log(offset);
        var requestObject = $.ajax({url:'http://xbiod.osu.edu/OJ_Break/getTaxonOccurrences?tnuid=23188&place_id=137&show_children=Y&basic_only=N&format=jsonp&key=750B&version=2&limit=25&offset='+offset, type:'GET', dataType:'jsonp', crossDomain:true});

        requestObject.always(function(jData, status) 
        {
            console.log(offset);
            var result = '';
            console.log(jData.data.occurrences);
                for (var count = 0; count < jData.data.occurrences.length; count++) 
                {
                    var occurrence = jData.data.occurrences[count];
                    for (var i = 0; i < county.length; i++)
                    {
                        if ( occurrence.locality.hier.pol2.place_name == county[i][0] )
                        {
                            county[i][1]+=1;
                            console.log(county[i]);
                        }
                    }

                    result += '<div>' + occurrence.locality.hier.pol2.place_name + '</div>';
                }

                $('#included_id').html(result);
        });
      offset += 25;
      loop++;
    }

    colorMap();
});
```

I'm calling the function loader which uses a callback function colorMap, however the callback never runs. I can't figure out why it doesn't work despite countless examples showing that this is the right way. Basically, I want to edit the map after the loader function finishes. The ajax was altered to not work but it's not really relevant to my question.

Comment: You shadow the outer `colorMap` with the argument of the same name. I suppose that's not intentional...

Answer (score 0):

jQuery passes a reference of itself to the `ready()` handler, so `colorMap` is actually a reference to `jQuery` when you try to invoke it:

```
// your `loader(colorMap)` function gets passed jQuery
$(document).ready(function loader(colorMap){
    ...
    // this is the same as calling `jQuery()` here, since `colorMap`
    // is now a reference to jQuery
    colorMap(); 
});
```

To fix it, simply remove `colorMap` from your `loader(colorMap)` arguments list.

I.e.,

```
$(document).ready(function loader() { ...
```

Comment: That works, accept colorMap now gets called before the rest of the code which results in the initial county array. I need colorMap to run after the while loop.

Comment: Well, it does run after the `while` loop... just not after the asynchronous requests that you kick off within the while loop come back. Can you help me understand the purpose of the `while` loop? It looks like you just do the exact same thing twice.

Comment: The api I'm using uses a limit and offset value to grab data in batches. I was under the impression that a callback was the only way ensure a function runs after another.

Answer (score 0):

I put colorMap in a setTimeout and it worked as I wanted. However, my embedded svg map doesn't update with jQuery in IE, but just fine in Chrome and Firefox.